# How to move particles independently from particle emitter in andengine

Tags: java, android, andengine, particle-system, particles

I have a working particle emitter that is attached to another entit. What I have now is that when I drag (move) entity with emitter all created partcles move as well. Emitter creates particles that should move only upwards, but when Idrag emitter to the right all particles are moved to the right as well. I understand that its because of attachment to the entity. What I would like to achieve is that when particle shows its independent from emitter, so I can drag emitter and particle just stays on its original course.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try attaching particle system to the scene and updating its position (or emitter position) when sprite moves (in onManagedUpdate function).

You can also try adding your own IParticleModifier and override onUpdateParticle to calculate proper position during update and set velocity/acceleration for each particle. (see Andengine Cookbook)

Comment: You, sir, are smart! First option worked, I update emitters position in its onUpdate method. Thanks